# jtree node isCollapsed/isExpanded does not work

Tags: java, swing, jtree, treenode

I have this piece of code

```
if (tree.isCollapsed(new TreePath(selectedNode.getPath()))){
      tree.expandPath(new TreePath(selectedNode.getPath()));
}else{              
      tree.collapsePath(new TreePath(selectedNode.getPath()));
}
```

The problem is, if I double click on the node in jtree, isCollapsed returns wrong values. It happens, when I double click on the node, it is expand thed and than I double click again on the same node and isCollapsed returns again true. It happens only when I click directly on the node title (i.e. on some letter). When I click in the row but next to the title, everything is fine...
What is the problem?

Comment: Doesn't double clicking a node open and close it?